# How to save Real Time data within an Android application to view later?

Tags: android

I am creating an application using an EEG NeuroSky headset that measures the attention and mediation levels of a user over a certain time period as they play a game.

The attention and mediation levels are recorded from the headset and displayed in real time on screen every second (as ints between 0 and 100). It is very similar to the NeuroSky application demostrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tr4CjtGtvg)

I would like to be able to save them and then view them after in a separate Activity after the game has finished, either as int values or in a graph form. I.e. to be able to view what the users mediation level was at 36 seconds, and what the attention level was at 45 seconds etc.

Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?

Specific area of concern:

note- I dont know how  to save the value of each msg.arg1?

```
case TGDevice.MSG_MEDITATION:
                meditation.setText("Meditation: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");

                if(msg.arg1<=35){

                    //if mediation level is low it turns red
                    meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                }else if((msg.arg1<=70)&&(msg.arg1>=35)){
                      meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }else{

                        meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }

                break;
```

Code from where data is being recorded:

```
/**
     * Handles messages from TGDevice
     * 
     */
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // msg.what determines the type of each message
            switch (msg.what) {
            case TGDevice.MSG_EEG_POWER:

                //WILL NEED TO CHANGE TO PUTPUT TO SCREEN. 
//              Log.d("LSD", "highAlpha: " + eegPower.highAlpha);
//              Log.d("LSD", "lowAlpha: " + eegPower.lowAlpha);
//              Log.d("LSD", "highBeta: " + eegPower.highBeta);
//              Log.d("LSD", "lowBeta: " + eegPower.lowBeta);
//              Log.d("LSD", "lowGamma: " + eegPower.lowGamma);
//              Log.d("LSD", "midGamma: " + eegPower.midGamma);
//              Log.d("LSD", "delta: " + eegPower.delta);
//              Log.d("LSD", "theta: " + eegPower.theta);

                break;
            case TGDevice.MSG_STATE_CHANGE:

                // actual value of the message is determined by msg.arg1
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case TGDevice.STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    meditation.append("Connecting...\n");
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    meditation.append("Connected.\n");
                    device.start();
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_NOT_FOUND:
                    meditation.append("Could not connect any of the paired BT devices.  Turn them on and try again.\n");
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_ERR_NO_DEVICE:
                    meditation.append("No Bluetooth devices paired.  Pair your device and try again.\n");
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_ERR_BT_OFF:
                    meditation.append("Bluetooth is off.  Turn on Bluetooth and try again.");
                    break;

                case TGDevice.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    meditation.append("Disconnected.\n");
                } /* end switch on msg.arg1 */

                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_POOR_SIGNAL:
                //meditation.append("PoorSignal: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_HEART_RATE:
                meditation.append("Heart rate: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_RAW_DATA:
                /* Handle raw EEG/EKG data here */
                //tv.append("RAW EEG: " + msg.arg1); Note: commented out as trying to get the exact figs (gamma etc)
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_ATTENTION:
                //meditation.append("Attention: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");

                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_MEDITATION:
                meditation.setText("Meditation: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");

                if(msg.arg1<=35){

                    //if mediation level is low it turns red
                    meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                }else if((msg.arg1<=70)&&(msg.arg1>=35)){
                      meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }else{

                        meditation.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }

                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_BLINK:
                meditation.append("Blink: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            default:
                break;

            } /* end switch on msg.what */

            //sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN); May need to use this again if the scroll view is needed!

        } /* end handleMessage() */

    }; /* end Handler */
```

Comment: Write each data point to a file (including values and timestamp), then display it in another activity or app.  It should be fairly trivial.

Comment: Im sorry but I am not sure what you mean, I am fairly new to android!

Comment: That isn't an android thing, its basic programming.

Comment: Ok, how do i save each data point then? I would like to use SQlite as a database

Answer (score 0):

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

gives you the System Time as set by the system clock as unix timestamp

Comment: Basically I just want to be able to save the data from each second that it changes, i.e. the value at one second, 2 seconds etc